# jQuery select next sibling by class with one class that contains multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright this sounds complicated but it's kinda simple, but after 2 hours of Googling I give up. If someone could please help I'd be greatful

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="post-93 product type-product status-publish hentry first instock"></li>
    <li class="post-87 product type-product status-publish hentry instock"></li>
    <li class="post-85 product type-product status-publish hentry last instock"></li>
    <li class="post-78 product type-product status-publish hentry first instock"></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the jquery I have so far.

```
$('.products > li').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next(".last").insertAfter( /* a piece of html will go here */));
    })
```

the list is generated by Wordpress dynamically, and rather than try and hack the code myself, I'd rather just manipulate what is on the screen.

The end result is to display the product with a sort of drop down style box like in a Google Image search. The first and last classes are added to the li items dynamically set by the short code [product_sku=99 colums=3 rows=3] where colums = left to right.

**TL;DR** use .next() to select a class in an element with multiple classes. By default .next() will not work unless you list every class in that element (as far as I can gather).

Thinking about this I probably also need to check that the current element doesn't contain the class last before searching.... anyways anyone have any ideas? I'm thinking it's something simple but I can't figure it out.

Edit: Attempting to Clarify the TLDR statement.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. _"I need to select the ".last" class from the next sibling in line."_ doesn't make sense to me based on the HTML you posted.

Comment: If I were to click <li class="post-93......"></li>, I want to insert a div after the next sibling ( <li> ) with the class of ".last" which in this case would be <li class="post-85..."></li>

Comment: A div can't be a child of an UL, so you probably mean a LI element, and you already have a LI element with that class, should that just be moved up, or should a new element be inserted. You wrote a lot, but described almost nothing ?

Comment: The element being clicked on them seems irrelevant in terms of finding the desired locations. The click would seem to just serve as the trigger to insert something after the LI that has class last.

Comment: While this is true, I can add a </ul> <div class="foo">bar</div><ul> which is almost like reverse logic of PHP tags but it still would fulfill the requirements.

@j08691 right, but in this case I'm getting the product code (class) from the LI and then displaying it in a larger box along with a quantity selector and an add to cart below that row of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the comments I think this might be what you're after. 
It will insert a new `li` after the `.last` whenever you click on an li.

```
$('.products').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  // get any data from clicked li by using $(this)

  // only look for product li
  $('li.last.product').after('<li>yo</li>');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/eXAfArA/1/edit